# Height depends on the text in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: Height depends on div]

I am passing a Component with different text present in an array using map() but it is giving me this output.

I want all to be in a straight line having same height of each component without depending on content. How do I fix this?

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-paper-f1hqo?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: probably needs vertical-align setting

Comment: it is really difficult to answer if you don't provide what you tried to get this output.

i guess the height looks same for boxes from diagram.. so what you can do is to parent you should assign display to flex and align items property to center so all boxes will be in straight line.

also set the minimum or max height to boxes so they will be same

Comment: I have provided the sand box link. I want the in a straight line, having same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `verticalAlign: "middle"` to your Box style.

However, I would recommend using Flexbox with `justify-content` and/or `align-items`.

**Edit:**
Simple example with flexbox:

```css
html, * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  padding: 1em;
}

.box {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0.75rem;
  padding: 0.75%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">Multiple Words to continue</div>
  <div class="box">words</div>
  <div class="box">Multiple Words to continue</div>
  <div class="box">words</div>
<div>
```

Comment: It worked with verticallyAlign, but how would you use flexbox for this.

Comment: @AyushRai see edit.